# flutter build apk failed for task ':mobile_number:verifyReleaseResources'

Tags: flutter, dart, apk

I am trying to build apk from my terminal but its giving this issue:

```
    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':mobile_number:verifyReleaseResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.VerifyLibraryResourcesTask$Action
   > Android resource linking failed
     ERROR:C:\Users\SEVDALI55\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\0ce731f8c62e88af9af421907435d7da\transformed\core-1.8.0\res\values\values.xml:104:5-113:25: AAPT: e
rror: resource android:attr/lStar not found.


* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BU�LD FAILED in 1m 15s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                           76,1s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: I know mobile_number package giving this issue but I must use this plugin. I dont know how can I fix this problem.